# Condition Codes Of NEON Operations

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

The Assembler Reference from the ARM Compiler Toolchain documentation refers to the “Condition codes on page 3-32” on many if not all of the vector instructions, yet I find myself unable to access any of it.

Specifically, can one get the `Z`(ero) flag of a `VEOR` result?

Comment: You are wrong: No neon instruction can be executed conditionally or affect CPSR.

Comment: There are NEON instructions which can be executed conditionally according to The ARM Compiler armasm User Guide. “In ARM state, except for the instructions that are common to both VFP and NEON, you cannot use a condition code to control the execution of NEON instructions.” [VLDR, VLDM, VMOV, VMRS, VMSR, VSTM and VSTR]

Comment: Jake is correct that vector instructions like VEOR don't *write* CPSR.  Predication is a totally separate mechanism from having condition-code *outputs*.  It appears Jake did over-state the inability to predicate any NEON instruction, but that quote from the manual doesn't imply anything about any NEON instructions writing CPSR.

Comment: To check if two vectors were equal, probably do a packed compare as two 64-bit halves, then maybe `vand` the 64-bit halves together, and extract the low 32 bits of that (all bits will be the same in those 64 bits, so the low 32 matches the part you aren't extracting).  That'll stall the pipeline on some microarchitectures, apparently, since integer and NEON can be weakly coupled without good scheduling between them.

Comment: Only `shared` VFP and neon instructions (such as `vldm`) can be executed conditionally. And you may put up to five (if I remember correctly) "conditional" neon instruction inside  an `IT/IF` block in `thumb2` mode. But fundamentally, no neon instruction can be executed conditionally. And you should avoid writing assembly codes in thumb mode in the first place.

Comment: The issue is that I always find myself joining these 128-bits with extra instructions. You guessed correct @PeterCordes. VMOV a vector into two registers followed by AND and CBZ is how it works now.

Comment: If you're "always" doing that with 128-bit vectors, maybe you're using them for things SIMD isn't good at.  Also, why `and` + `cbz` instead of just `tst` / `bne` to set flags according to their bitwise AND?  Or just `ands` / `bne`.  I guess if you only need to branch forward, `and` / `cbz` might perform the same.  Also, is there a `vmov` that will get part of both 64-bit halves of a vector into a scalar register in a single instruction? If not, wouldn't it be more efficient to do like I suggested and `vceq` or `vtst`? Oh, NEON maybe doesn't have 64-bit integer element size, so 2 halves of a D?

Comment: Probably right again @PeterCordes. I use NEON to speed up simple data checks (like equality) because NEON has faster memory access. The 40 to 90 % speed gain is nice, yet could be significantly better without the boolean "fusion". I was hoping that I missed something obvious. No status registers is a good answer. Why can't ARM just mention that in their docs?  Glad to have you guys here. 

Comment: For context @Peter: doing VLD1 with 4 D2, then VEOR/VCEQ, then join VAND B16.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/i/neon-and-vfp-programming/veor doesn't mention the possibility of an `S` suffix to make it set condition codes.  So unlike `and` vs. `ands`, it can't write them.  If an instruction writes condition codes even without an `s` suffix, the docs would always say so.  (I hope?  I'm more familiar with x86 docs.)

Comment: The page has a "See also" section which lists condition codes exclusively. That is super misleading @PeterCordes. ARM should both drop that section and state how NEON does not affect status registers explicitly.

Comment: That section / link describes how condition codes can be an *input* (as a predicate), or not.  The fact that NEON instructions can't safely be predicated is important to document, because the default is that any instruction can be predicated.  Notice how that linked page says "The instructions that **can be conditional**"

Answer (score 1):

Is this documentation more helpful: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0597/2020-12/SIMD-FP-Instructions/VEOR--Vector-Bitwise-Exclusive-OR-

The Arm Architecture docs give the how it works, where the [Compiler docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/Advanced-SIMD-Instructions--32-bit-/VEOR) give just what it does. (Note Compiler 6.6 doc there, vs Compiler 5 doc in comments).  Compiler docs, unfortunately for you, seem to displace instruction set docs from searches! So need to search specifically for them.

Comment: That page you linked includes "*If CPSR.DIT is 1 and this instruction **passes its condition execution check**:* which seems to (incorrectly) imply it does support predication, and pseudocode `if ConditionPassed() then`.  But the A32 encoding having the top 4 bits shown as `1` in the encoding which indicates the only condition allowed is AL = Always?  Maybe useful to contrast with https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0597/2020-12/Base-Instructions/EOR--EORS--register---Bitwise-Exclusive-OR--register-- (one form of scalar `eor`) which does show the `cond` field in the encoding.

Comment: Oops, the question was asking if VEOR writes the condition codes as outputs, not about predication.  So yeah, the `if setflags then` in the scalar `eor`, vs. the lack in `veor`, is the indication that it doesn't write flags, along with lack of any mention of flag-writing anywhere in the text.  So I think the contrast with a flag-writing instruction is still important, to point out what would be there in an instruction that did write flags.  But yes, good link to a more useful part of the ARM online manuals.